# how to use hasOne for two other detail models in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have one main table and two detail tables
table names: tb_main, tb_detail1, tb_detail2

```
tb_main
id, detail_code
tb_detail1
id, main_id
tb_detail2
id, main_id
```

I want get detail data using one function in main model

```
public function detail()
    {
        if(detail_code == 1)
            return $this->hasOne(Detail1::class, 'main_id', 'id');
        else
            return $this->hasOne(Detail2::class, 'main_id', 'id');
    }
```

Any ideas? please help me!
And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: how to getting detail_code,this one direct getting from Auth?

Comment: detail_code value has 1 (for tb_detail1) and 2(for tb_detail2)

Comment: @Dream811.also show how you call relationship and detail_code  is from request or db

Comment: What is the output that you are getting as of now ?

Comment: @Dream811 Okay then need to where to call this relationship because directly not used like this.

Comment: I want to get detail1 or detail2 table data using "main->detail;"

Comment: @Dream811 from where detail_code  values comes ?

Comment: @JohnLobo, it will be store when save data

Comment: try public function detail()
    {
        if($this->detail_code == 1)
            return $this->hasOne(Detail1::class, 'main_id', 'id');
        else
            return $this->hasOne(Detail2::class, 'main_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: @JohnLobo, I need your help again. after run this code 
Main::where('bIsDel', 0)->with('detail');
I met this error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::addEagerConstraints()
Could you possibly to give me a hint for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this->detail_code`

```
public function detail() { 

if($this->detail_code == 1) {

   return $this->hasOne(Detail1::class, 'main_id', 'id'); 

}else{

   return $this->hasOne(Detail2::class, 'main_id', 'id');

}
```

Comment: I need your help again. after run this code Main::where('bIsDel', 0)->with('detail'); I met this error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::addEagerConstraints() Could you possibly to give me a hint for me?

Comment: @Dream811 look like detail is not relationship method. firs check detail return relationship or not

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that in the `relation` method. First, declare all relations in the main model like so:

```
public function detail1()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Detail1::class, 'main_id');
}

public function detail2()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Detail2::class, 'main_id');
}
```

Then write one method to decide what to do based on `detail_code` :

```
public function detail()
{
    if($this->detail_code == 1)
        return $this->detail1()->first();

    return $this->detail2()->first();
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't that be done in the relation method ?

Comment: @Vagabond 
Technically, it is not wrong to do that, but what if you need a specific relation in one scenario? in this example what if you need `detail1()` specifically? Think of relations as something static that will never change. In some best practices, developers use `Repository Pattern` to separate data fetching logic and relations. This pattern is commonly used in Symfony as entities(something like models) and repositories(data fetching logic and queries)

Comment: @Vagabond Another thing that I forgot to say is that if you want to load relation with the `load('detail')` method this means that you don't have any data of a record in your model. then the data that is going to fetch is will be wrong. in this example, the `detail_code` property will be null and then in the `load()` method, it will always fetch detail2().